# class variables

Tags: java

This might be a dumb question but I had this question hover around me. Is there any difference between class variables and member variables in java or they both one and the same.

```
class Example {
  protected String str;
  public static String str1 = "xyz";
}
```

I know that str1 is a class variable, is str also a class variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the difference is, there is only one per class when we talk about class attributes and there is one per object when we talk about instance attribute.

In your code `protected String str` declares  an instance attribute ( or member variable as you call it )  and `public static String str1 = "xyz"` declares a class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference.

Member variables are tied to an instance object of the class. So the variable's value can be different for different instance objects.

The static variable is one for the whole class - you don't need to instantiate an object to access it.

```
class A {
   public int memberVar;
   public static int staticVar;
}

void Test() {
   A obj = new A();

   int var = obj.memberVar;
   //var = A.memberVar -- wrong!

   //vs

   var = A.staticVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same, and str isn't a class variable - the "static" indicates a class variable.

The fundamental difference is that class (static) variables can be thought of as shared between all instance of the class, whereas there is an independent copy of each member (instance) variable for each instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is not a class variable. `str` is an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

**[Class variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable)**

> a class variable is a variable defined
>   in a class (i.e. a member variable) of
>   which a single copy exists, regardless
>   of how many instances of the class
>   exist

**[Instance variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable)**

> a variable defined in a class (i.e. a
>   member variable), for which each
>   object of the class has a separate
>   copy

By these definitions, `str1` is a class variable, and `str` is not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference.  str1 is a class variable that has 1 value for all instances of the class.  The str variable is an instance variable, and each instance of Example (aka, new Example()) can have a different value of str, but all instances of Example will share the same value of str1.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to implement a counter inside your class that counts how many instances have been created, you will see immediately why class variables can do the work, while instance variables can not.

```
public class MyClass {
   private static int count;

   public MyClass() {
      count++;
      ...
   }

   public static int getCount() {
      return count;
   }
   ...
}
```

You can call `MyClass.getCount();` even before having created a single MyClass instance.

Answer (score 0):

str1 is a class variable as static is the modifier to it. static means variable belongs to a class not to the instance.
str variable does not have static modifier which makes it member or instance variable.
each instance of a class will have its own copy of member variable